# jquery copy div to div on page load

Tags: jquery

Trying to do this on page load within same page:

CSS:

```
#item1, #item2, #item3 {visibility: hidden;}
```

HTML (these will not be shown)

```
<div id="item1">Something1</div> 
<div id="item2">Something2</div>
<div id="item3">Something3</div>
```

These div's will be empty normally, but after page loads they will be populated based on what is on the above div's.

```
<div id="real-content">
    <div id="duplicate-item1">Something1</div>
    <div id="duplicate-item2">Something2</div>
    <div id="duplicate-item3">Something3</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  I may try .clone() but will also look into the codes you guys posted below.  Thanks in advance..

Turns out .clone() is the solution..

```
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
```

How can I take the .above and turn that into more global?  Say I have 20 div's that need cloning?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Whatever is in "item1" will be duplicated in "duplicate-item1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#idContainerWithHiddenDivs div').each(function(){
    var idToCopy = $(this).attr('id');
    vat newID = 'duplicate-'+idToCopy;
    var $newDiv = $(this).clone().attr('id', newID);
    $('#real-content').append($newDiv);
});
```

I think is a good way to do it.

Quick example : http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/6/ corrected fiddler, the last one wasn't working.

Or maybe you may want to use this one : http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/11/ or you may want to try : http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/14/ after your last comment.

Comment: How can this be done on a more global level?  Let's say I want to have 20 fields cloned/duplicated.

Comment: Thank you.. can you also look at my latest edit?  Perhaps you can help with .clone()

Comment: ahh :) I'm 16 hours in today on something that is boggling my mind.  Thanks :)

Comment: I updated Fiddle and found a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/10/
It displays correctly in the result, but if you inspect the element, there are 6 div's instead of 3. Is there a way to just write to the div's instead of creating new ones?

Comment: Added new one. http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/11/ Or do you want only to replace the ids

Comment: Just to replace the contents inside of the div would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#real-content").find("div").each(function(){
   var ID = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
   $(this).html($("#"+ID[1]).html());
});
```